# Where is my cookie?

Tags: php, cookies

I have this code in login.php

```
if ( $sth->execute() ) {
    $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ( $row ) {
        var_dump($row); // See below
        $_SESSION['login'] = $row['login'];
        setcookie('login', $row['login'], time() * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
        if ( $row['right'] == ACCESS_ADMIN ) {
            echo "true"; // true
            $_SESSION['right'] = ACCESS_ADMIN;
            setcookie('right', $row['login'], time() * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
        }
    }
}


var_dump($row) - array(3) 
{ 
    ["login"]=> string(6) "phplox"
    ["password"]=> string(32) "827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b"
    ["right"]=> string(5) "admin" 
} ?>
<br>
```

Ok, all right. Go to index.php.

```
<?php var_dump($_COOKIE) ?> `// array(1) { ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(26) "o05mr9luc2ok8ieadss4v9mhg0" }`
```

But if

```
<?php var_dump($_SESSION) ?> //
```

the result is:

```
array(3) 
{
    ["request_token"]=> string(32) "335f1dcd4283889f0f2fe602cfa36d71"
    ["login"]=> string(6) "phplox" ["right"]=> string(5) "admin" 
}
```

Comment: So, what is your exact problem?

Comment: What you are trying? What you wants?

Comment: @Rune the cookie is not being set? I think he was pretty clear with that... @row248: Change `time() * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60` to `time() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60`. Probably wont solve your problem but its good to fix it now.

Comment: Me need cookie with login and access.

Comment: Ok Cookie Monster. What is the output of `var_dump(ACCESS_ADMIN);` ?

Comment: Can't you just use the session? Shouldn't make a difference and would be much more secure. And have you done an http trace (using firebug for example) to make sure the cookie actually gets sent to the client?

Comment: @row248 the `time()` fix I mentioned earlier could fix it. Its probably overflowing to an earlier date and not setting it.

Comment: It would still be there. Setting it in the past would delete it.

Comment: var_dump(ACCESS_ADMIN) return 'admin'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send any output before setting cookies. Cookies are sent via a HTTP header and so they must be sent before any output has been sent to the browser. Here, you echo something, then try to set the cookie:

```
            echo "true"; // <--- REMOVE THIS
            $_SESSION['right'] = ACCESS_ADMIN;
            setcookie('right', $row['login'], time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)); // add to the time, don't multiply time()
```

You can also check the return value of `setcookie()`, which returns a boolean `false` if output has already been sent.

Comment: Possibly, but he's not complaining of the buffer error and for all we know on line 1 he has `ob_start();`

Comment: @row248 yes, as said in my answer - the cookie can't be said because of the `echo`.

Comment: @row248 then you have some other output elsewhere. Look back through all of your code for any `echo` or output. Also check if there's any whitespace before the opening `<?php` tag.

Comment: Maybe its because i have `require 'nav-menu.php'` before setcookie()?

Comment: Yes, if you are outputting html then that will stop the cookie. Any output at all: html, php warnings, whitespace - all will stop the cookie. It might be easier to move your `setcookie()` call to at the start of your code.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
time() * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60
```

Overflows, so it wraps around the `int` value and creates a value that refers to the past, thus the browser will not create the cookie. Change it to:

```
time() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60
```

Also, as MrCode said, don't send output before sending cookies unless you use `ob_start()`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Im delete echo "true". And change time() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 but its not work.

Comment: Check the return value of `setcookie()` then.